# Erro: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid

Tags: php, laravel, auth

Pessoal estou usando laravel 5.2 e fui realizar uma autentication, porem quando rodo o comando `php artisan make:auth` funciona perfeito, mas na pratica não... Quando clico em login ou register me da esse erro :

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Como posso arrumar?
Composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: amigo instalei por composer, é mac e tem permissao ... mas o meu arquivo .env nem o .env.exemple existe ,,,,

Comment: o estranho que nenhum projeto meu tem o .env... Vou postar meu composer.json

Comment: Amigo desculpa não entendi os comandos... acabei de criar outro projeto para teste e também veio sem o .env.exemple .... Ondep osso arrumar ?

Comment: Segui o tuturial no propio site do laravel ... fiz tudo na minha pasta raiz ... para criar o projeto usei composer create-project laravel/laravel

Comment: dentro da pasta composer existe varios arquivos, cache, vendor, composer .joson... algum deles é ?

Comment: rodei o curl e tudo .... dei o comando como falou ...agora veio o .env, vou testar o auth

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento deu certo tambem ...  pro favor cria uma resposta para dar como resolvido ....

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento que bom ... Muito Obrigado ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se navegou até a pasta do projeto e não existe o `.env.example` é porque houve alguma falha na instalação do Laravel, quando instalamos a primeira vez o Laravel pelo composer ele gera uma cópia dentro da pasta do composer, então se criar novos projetos (provavelmente pelo `artesian`) ele vai buscar da cópia local, verifique a pasta que foi instalado, geralmente o local que fica salvo é o `~/.composer/vendor/bin`, se acha que algo falhou na instalação do composer, use o comando desta maneira:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Quando for criar um projeto use o parâmetro `--prefer-dist`, assim:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel meuprimeiroprojeto
```

Pra conferir se ficou tudo ok, navegue até a pasta digitando:

```
cd meuprimeiroprojeto
ls -a
```

Vai exibir todos arquivos, deve aparecer o `.env.example`

Answer (score 0):

Antes de mais nada, Você deve gerar sua APP_KEY:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Se ainda assim não estiver funcionando, cheque no arquivo **config/app.php** se está definido como:

```
'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'
```

E se o arquivo **.env** existe... se não, você deve renomear o **.env.example** para **.env**

Comment: amigo o .env n existe mesmo onde crio ? pois nem o .env nem o .env.exemple encontro ?

Comment: o arquivo **.env.exemple** ou o próprio **.env** fica na raiz do projeto... lembrando que no linux os arquivos que começão com . ficam ocultos, pra edita-los basta rodar o  **nano .env**

Comment: ja tentei ver nos ocultos e nada também ....